# Why "time patrol Goku" attacked "DBS Goku"?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

In the first episode of Dragon Ball Heroes we saw as the preview showed, the battle between Goku SSJ4 ("time patrol Goku") and Goku SSB ("DBS Goku"). Why "time patrol Goku" attacked "DBS Goku"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see a better representation of this in the manga. Xeno Goku was in search of Fu and charges towards him. This attack is blocked by Goku and Goku remarks on his unbelievable power and turns SSJB and a fight begins between the two of them.

Two other interesting points to note is that Xeno Goku has not experienced anything from the ROF saga and is hence unaware of Super Saiyan Blue (Note: He is aware of the Super Saiyan God transformation). He is surprised by Goku's Blue hair. Also, an actual battle engages between the two of them, unlike in the anime which SSJB Goku ends up winning and Xeno Goku remarks that SSJB Goku was one step ahead of him.

[image: Xeno Goku charges towards Fu]

[image: Goku Blocks the attack]

Comment: hmmm interesting, what does he know about the Super Saiyan God? did he fight him or something?

Comment: Well, he is aware of Super Saiyan God definitely however, it is up for debate as to whether he attained it himself or not. In Ultimate Mission X, Xeno Goku states how with the help of his allies, Goku was able to turn Super Saiyan God. However, while some people (Including wiki, states he himself did turn Super Saiyan God), however some people argue that he is referring to an alternate version of him who did because of the Japanese translation.

Comment: You mean some people thinks Xeno Goku obtained super saiyan god? Which transformation would be stronger then, super saiyan god or super saiyan 4?